# How to match multiple sequences

Tags: javascript, regex

How is it possible to match more than one string with regular expressions?

Here I want to match both `name` and `txt`, but only `name` is matched?

```
var reg = new RegExp('%([a-z]+)%', "g");
reg.exec('%name% some text %txt%');
```

Comment: Ok, now both your answers return `["%name%", "%txt%"]`, but how to return only `["name", "txt"]` ??

Comment: Use the captured group instead of the whole match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The g flag does work but needs to be executed on the same string multiple times

```
var reg = new RegExp('%([a-z]+)%', "g");
var str = '%name% some text %txt%';
var result;

while( result = reg.exec( str ) ) { // returns array of current match
    console.log( result[1] ); // index 0 is matched expression. Thereafter matched groups.
}​
```

The above outputs `name` & `txt` to the console.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/Kt48N/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead:

```
'%name% %txt%'.match(reg); //["%name%", "%txt%"]
```

[`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) only retrieves the first match (albeit with capturing groups).

If the capturing groups are important to you, you can use a loop:

```
var matches = [];
var str = '%name% some text %txt%';
var reg = new RegExp('%([a-z]+)%', "g");
while (match = reg.exec(str)){
    matches.push(match);
}
```

If you only want to keep the captured groups, use this instead:

```
matches.push(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `exec`:

```
'%name% some text %txt%'.match(reg);
```